# How do I check in bash if a process (or one of its children) is actually doing something (CPU/IO)?

Tags: bash, progress-bar

Actually, I would like to have some kind of progress bar.
I would like for the user to be able to recognize when the process "hangs".

Usually I will use it to show the progress of ./configure and make calls.

ADDENDUM: I need progress that makes no use of external tools. (no bar)

/proc/pid/stat is ok, but doesn't solve the problem about possible child processes

Comment: The one that **ghostdog74** linked to is a shell function that could be dropped directly into your script. It works in *many* Bourne-derived shells and uses *no* external tools.

Comment: Yeah but I can't imagine that this works with configure or make.
Actually maybe I used the wrong word, I need an activity indicator that will let the user know when the started commands (like configure and make) do nothing anymore (not IO, no CPU, nothing....)

Comment: Please clarify what you really want. Do you want a progress bar, CPU/IO stats, user notification of when a process "hangs" (not sure if this includes idle or wait, deadlock, seg fault, or not), and it needs to make use of no external tools like `cat` and `bash`  (like bar does)?

Comment: Is this programming related, or should it be moved to http://ServerFault.com/ (or http://SuperUser.com/ )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a general solution, then you're going to have to do recursive `ps -ppid ...` calls---or do a single big `ps` call that gets everything at once and parse it yourself to get all the descendants of your desired parent process. (You could prune the stuff you need to pay attention to by first getting the session leader or process group of your parent process, and then just doing a ps for processes with that session leader/process group. If you're lucky, no more pruning will be needed.)

But if you're dealing with ./configure and make calls specifically, why don't you pipe their output to a temp file and just watch that to see it's getting longer, or when it was last touched, or so on?

Answer (score 0):

[`dialog`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_(software)) has a progress bar.

As far as monitoring status (other than milestones in your code), you could probably parse `/proc/PID/status` or the output of `ps`.

**Edit:**

To get a list of child processes, parse the output of:

```
ps -ppid PID_OF_PARENT
```